# Google cloud cdn - unclear cache hit ratio

Tags: load-balancing, google-cloud-platform, cdn, google-cloud-cdn

I'm using google cloud cdn (Load balancer with a backend service) and the hit ration status is not very clear.
In the image below you can see:

1. Left image - **CDN view**  - Value of cache hit ratio is "**n/a**".
2. Right image - **Backend service view** - *upper* part (in green) - I see some responses which are served from cache - **0.6 RPS**.
3. Right image - **Backend service view**  - *lower* part (in red) - Cloud CDN cache hit is **0.00 RPS**.

[image]

**Can somebody help me to understand the differences between the 3 places?**

**And what is my current cache hit ratio?**

Answer (score 0):

I found an excellent answer provided by a user named Elving, explained why you are noticing these differences in StackOverflow forum, and you can see the detailed explanation in [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51989083/gcloud-cdn-cache-hit-ratio-unclear).

Comment: Thanks @Nur, i've rated his answer, but waiting for another answers.